# How to login website account with Python & Requests

Tags: python, authentication, redirect, python-requests

I'm trying to login onto 2 websites accounts with Python 3 and Requests module.
1st website is : https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#login and I need to grab information on this page after : https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#avoirs
2nd website is : https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/index.asp (after the login, there is a redirect to https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/login2.asp for another extra random security question within 4/5 choices, like place of birth, or first pet name) and after I need to grab information on this page : https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/statement-page.asp

The idea is to retrieve personnal account information to process it in another script.
I know how to use requests (on a basic level), but I'm struggling with those 2 specific website (I believe because of the way the password has to be inputed for the first, by clicking, and because of the redirect on the second).

```
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

URL1 = 'https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#login'
URL2 = 'https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#'
URL3 = 'https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/index.asp'
URL4 = 'https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/login2.asp'
URL5 = 'https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/statement-page.asp'

payload1 = {
    'username' : '000000',
    'password' : '000000'
}
payload2 = {
    'username' : '000000',
    'password' : '000000'
}
sub_payload1 = {
    'password' : 'aaaaaa'
}
sub_payload2 = {
    'password' : 'bbbbbb'
}
sub_payload3 = {
    'password' : 'cccccc'
}

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}


with requests.Session() as c:
    c.post(URL1, headers=headers, data=payload1)
    r = c.get(URL2, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)

with requests.Session() as d:
    d.post(URL3, headers=headers, data=payload2)
    #How to manage the redirection here to URL4?
    #How to test which extra security question is supplied and submit corresponding sub_payload?
    s = d.get(URL5, headers=headers)
    print(s.text)
```

For the 2nd website, I honestly have no idea how to handle the redirect and question testing...

Do payload 'username'/'password' have to match specific names from those websites forms?

Thanks for any help or guidance (I'm a beginner).

Comment: Read about [mcve]

Comment: you can gain the redirect url `req = d.post(URL3, headers=headers, data=payload2)` `req.url`.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make it work for the 2nd website, below the code if someone is interested. There was a hidden form field.
I'll open a new topic for the 1st website.

```
import requests, time
from lxml import html

LOGIN = 'https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/index.asp'
LOGIN2 = 'https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/login2.asp'
PROTECTED_PAGE = 'https://zone.mfgl.com/pensions/burohappold/statement-page.asp'
payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'action': 'login'
}
s_payload1 = {
    'answer': 'answer',
    'correctanswer': 'answer',
    'action': 'submit'
}
s_payload2 = {
    'answer': 'answer',
    'correctanswer': 'answer',
    'action': 'submit'
}
s_payload3 = {
    'answer': 'answer',
    'correctanswer': 'answer',
    'action': 'submit'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(LOGIN, data=payload)
    time.sleep(2)
    r = s.get(LOGIN2)
    #2nd login question test to submit appropriate sub_payload
    if 'XXXX' in r.text:
        s.post(LOGIN2, data=s_payload1)
    if 'YYYY' in r.text:
        s.post(LOGIN2, data=s_payload2)
    if 'ZZZZ' in r.text:
        s.post(LOGIN2, data=s_payload3)
    f = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE)

tree = html.fromstring(f.content)
a = tree.xpath('//td/text()')
index = a.index("Total")
Funds = a[32]
print(Funds)
```